Inserting a column into a csv that pulls from the name of the file in python
I'm trying to insert a column of "StatementDate" into a csv, where the date is in the title of the csv. This is dynamic and will change week to week.
The formatting of the title is the same, the dates will change though.
Example:
011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv
I want to extract just the date portion
My current set up:
df = pd.read_csv("011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv")
df["011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv"] = os.path.basename('011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv')
data.append(df)

This gives me an error that 'data' is not defined
I was thinking something like
df.insert(loc=0, column='StatementDate', value=[date from file name]
Would a regex work to pull just the date out somehow?

Well, your DataFrame is df, then you use data. data is undefined. Also why would you use append? It's now deprecated and anyway was used to add a row. It looks like your question is mostly due to not knowing very well the pandas API. I would recommend to carefully read the documentation.

df.insert(loc=0, column='StatementDate', value=os.path.basename('/your/path/to/011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv') seems OK

Your first problem is that the variable data doesn't exist. You want to create a column with the date, but your question doesn't mention anything about what that data.append is about. Is it part of the question at all?

As @mozway's comment points out, you're calling data without ever having defined a data variable, which is why you're getting a NameError.
On top of that, os.path.basename('011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv') will just return the string '011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv', so it should be sufficient to just store the filename in a variable, given you already know the filename.
that being said, you don't necessarily have to use regex here if you don't want to, assuming that the filename formats are consistent.
You could do something like
file = '011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv'
date = file.split("_")[-1].strip(".csv")

or, if you'd like to use regex, something like
file = '011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv'
date = re.search('\d{2}-\d{2]-\d{4}', file).group()

of course, this regex example I've provided assumes that the date formatting is also consistent across filenames, but obviously the regex can be tailored to whatever your specific needs are.
Otherwise, as others have pointed out, the df.append method is deprecated, and was used for inserting rows, not columns.
Instead, you could use pd.concat, or you can use the alternate function you mentioned in your question. Regardless, I would suggest closely reading through the pandas docs to get a better understanding though.

The error comes from the line data.append(df) - the variable data doesn't exist. But the question is about how to add the date, so I will focus on that. The naming convention seems to be that the underscore is used to separate the name into 3 fields. Although a regex would work, I think it is simpler to keep with your use of os.path and then split the name on the separator character.
When you create a new column using the date, pandas will fill the entire column with the value.
import pandas as pd
import os

filename = "011J9O00_WA_07-10-2024.csv" # TODO: Hardcoded for test
_id, state, date  = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0].split("_")
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df["statementDate"] = date
print(df)

